# Decode nested JSON

Tags: json

I tried to decode my nested JSON:

```
{"Data":{"Recipes":{"Recipe_7":{"ID":"7","TITLE":"Wurstel","TEXT":"Kochen","COUNT_PERSONS":"4","DURATION":"10","USER_ID":"1","DATE":"2011-09-09 18:38:20"}}},"Message":null,"Code":200}
```

with the following:

```
include('php/get_recipe_byID.php');
$jsonstring = $a;
echo $jsonstring;
$obj = json_decode($jsonstring);
print_r($obj->Data);
print_r($obj->data[0]->Recipe_7->title);
```

print_r($obj->Data); echoes

```
stdClass Object ( [Recipes] => stdClass Object ( [Recipe_7] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 7 [TITLE] => Wurstel [TEXT] => Kochen [COUNT_PERSONS] => 4 [DURATION] => 10 [USER_ID] => 1 [DATE] => 2011-09-09 18:38:20 ) ) )
```

print_r($obj->data[0]->Recipe_7->title); echoes

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$data in /var/www/recipe_search.php on line 126

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/recipe_search.php on line 126
```

I think my syntax is wrong, isn´t it?

Answer (score 0):

It should `$obj->Data`, right?

### PHP variables are case sensitive. SO `$obj->data` and $obj->Data

EDIT:

Store the index in variable to  dynamically access, object values, as show below

`$recipe_index = 'Recipe_'. $_GET['id']. 
print_r($obj->Data->Recipes->$recipe_index]->TITLE);`

Comment: print_r($obj->Data->Recipes->Recipe_7->TITLE);

works now....

But I want the ID to be dynamic like
print_r($obj->Data->Recipes->Recipe_.$_GET['id']->TITLE); but that doesn´t work

Comment: try  $recipe_index = 'Recipe_'. $_GET['id']. Then print_r($obj->Data->Recipes->$recipe_index]->TITLE);

Comment: Thank you!! robert, please post your reply as answer that I can mark it as the right answer!